# jQuery ajax not passing post data to php page

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I try to get post data from using alert() and its worked problem is that data is not passing to php page result is always `{"success":false,"result":0}`

What I want is send password to php page and hash  it using  password_hash() and return result

```js
$('#spass').on('submit',function(){
  var that=$(this),
  contents=that.serialize();
  alert(contents);
  $.ajax({
    url:'passwordhashing.php',
    dataType:'json',
    data:contents,
    success:function(data){
      alert(JSON.stringify(data));
      console.log(data);
    }

  });

  return false; 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <form id="spass" >
    <h4>Change Your Password</h4>
    <input type='password'name="passc" >&nbsp;
    <!--<input type='password' name="cpass" id="cpass">&nbsp;-->
    <input type="submit">
      </form>


**this my php code**
<?php
header('Content-type: text/javascript');

$json=array(
    'success'=>false,
    'result'=>0
);



if(isset($_POST['passc']) && !empty($_POST['passc'])) {
   $pass=password_hash($_POST['passc'],PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
   $json['success']=true;
   $json['result']=$pass;
}
echo json_encode($json);

?>
```

Comment: where is your php code exactly ?

Answer (score 1):

You can test that your data has not actually been passed to a PHP page.

In the PHP code, do the following: echo $ _POST ['YOUR_VARIABLE'].

Check the INSPECT_ELEMENT / NETWORK browser to make sure you actually send data to the correct link. Your link may be relative, so you may be sending data to the wrong link.

So, try to put the entire link in the ajax url

```
$ .ajax ({
url: 'HTTP: //WHOLE_LINK_IN_HERE.COM/passwordhashing.php',
});
```

SET method in Ajax: type: "POST"

```
$.ajax({ 
  type: "POST", 
  url: url, 
  data: data, 
  success: success, 
  dataType: dataType 
});
```

Comment: but it's sending me default result that already in php page that mean's  the url is ok

Comment: SET method in Ajax: type: "POST"
```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

Comment: You can use $.post() and $.get() instead $.ajax      https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: $.post() method is worked for me thans for the help

Answer (score 0):

```
**i used $.post() instead of using $.ajax() and it fix my problem** 

$('#spass').on('submit',function(){
      var that=$(this),
      contents=that.serialize();
      alert(contents);
      $.post({
        url:'passwordhashing.php',
        dataType:'json',
        data:contents,
        success:function(data){
          alert(JSON.stringify(data));
          console.log(data);
        }

      });

      return false; 
    });
```